# Captured by a giant witch who wants to eat him

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

Looking for the the title/ author of a book of illustrated "silly" children's horror from around the early 1980's. The book is narrated by an uncle / grandfather to his (children?) about a strange adventure he had as a child. He is captured by a giant witch who plans to eat him but instead they get involved in telling stories to delay the meal.  The only story I can remember the details is they are watching a show on television about a bunch of large hairy monsters (much like the movie 'Critters' monsters) who have constantly snotty noses.  They eat a class of school children and one keeps asking for salt.  The witch and the kid both find it hilarious.  Somehow he escapes but is cursed to turn into a goofy monster by night.

The illustrations have little or no bright color, mostly dark tones, can't remember how much of a text / art ratio.  Short story, more on the funny side and not meant to scare.

Comment: Could it be one of the stories here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_and_the_Beanstalk#Variants

Comment: no sorry this was modern young adult fiction, I really doubt any relation to grimm fairy tales, etc.....

Answer (score 6):

It's called *Grandpa's Ghost Stories*.  I was searching for this same thing and the only way I found it was remembering that the art was similar to another story with a vine monster which was illustrated with black and green shades instead of the black and blue ones this book had.  The author/illustrator is James Flora.  Thank god someone else remembered this book, I've been googling it for about an hour!

Someone has even made a pseudo-animated version on Youtube:

Comment: Someone has even made a pseudoanimated version on youtube, although it's only the first part of the book with the dancing skeleton.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnJZk7jbAAs

Comment: Nvm, all the parts are there
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnJZk7jbAAs
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRc49GNOSZ8
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMGdQb__F-g

Comment: Yes that's exactly it, thank you!